# Trying to execute an appcmd command via Ansible

Tags: ansible

I trying to execute the below command and running into errors ... I tried with quoting around the arguments, that didn't help either

```
   - name: Add authorization rules to FTP site
     win_command: appcmd.exe 
   - args:
      chdir: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\
      stdin: set config "FTP_FW" 
   - section: system.ftpServer/security/authorization /+"[accessType='Allow',roles='domain\usera',permissions='Read, Write']" /commit:apphost
```

Tried with quoting, that didn't help ... Can you give me some pointers pls.

Comment: Could you format to make it look like a playbook and mention the error message you receive ?

Comment: `I trying to execute the below command and running into errors`. Please add the errors as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. I was able to figure out. I ran the complete command from win_command instead of having the arguments in stdin.